# Special use of linux find command together with zip

Tags: linux, shell

Imagine a folder structure like this:

- /411/folder1/
- /411/archive/
- /211/archive/
- /211/folder1/
- /211/folder2/

In each subfolder there will be files and more subfolders with files/folders. I'm interested in to zip all the files in the subfolders called 'archive' and ignore all other folders in the structure.

If I use the command: `find * -type d -name 'archive'`

The output will be like:

- 928/archive
- 973/archive
- 990/archive

What I'm interested in is to have an output like:

- 928/archive/file1.jpg
- 928/archive/file2.jpg
- 928/archive/folder1/file3.jpg

And so on so that I can use the commander: `find * -type d -name 'archive' [with some more/other options] | zip all_archive_files.zip -@`

How can this be done?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want a single zip with the contents of all the archives?

Answer (score 2):

you can match on the *whole* path using `-path` or `regex`: for example

`find . -regex './[0-9]+/archive/.*' -type f -exec zip all.zip {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

This is crude, but you could:

```
find . -type d -name 'archive' -exec find {} \; | zip stuff.zip -@
```

Comment: With the (not uncommon) caveat: filenames that have newlines in them will not work.

Comment: Caveat - OK, but why *not uncommon*? In about 40 years of programming, I don't remember having encountered a case, where someone by accident would have created a filename with embedded newline. Of course, this *can* happen, and one should be aware of this possibility, but I would call it a pretty rare situation.

Comment: I said the caveat itself was common, not filenames with newlines in them. In other words it's super common to write obvious but subtly wrong scripts like this.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to run `zip` takes filenames from the command line and with the `-r` flag the command will recurse into directories by itself. Consider

```
find . -name 'archive' -type d -exec zip -r all_archive_files.zip {} +
```

The `-exec` option will run `zip -r all_archive_files.zip ...` where `...` is replaced by a list of all the files that `find` found. Run it with `echo` between `-exec` and `zip` to see what it will do:

```
$ find . -name 'archive' -type d
411/archive
412/archive
488/archive
512/archive
$ find . -name 'archive' -type d -exec echo zip -r all_archive_files.zip {} +
zip -r all_archive_files.zip 411/archive 412/archive 488/archive 512/archive
```